# Can Riemann-Stieltjes integral exist if integrator $g$ is NOT of bounded variation on $[a, b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Can Riemann-Stieltjes integral exist if integrator $g$ is NOT of bounded variation on $[a, b]$?

In other words, can $I=\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dg(x)$ exist if $g$ is NOT in $BV(a, b)$?

Comment: Sure, e.g. if $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: See [*Differential properties of Young-Stieltjes integrals*](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s1-23/1/22/864030) by Burkill (1948) and *Integration with respect to functions of unbounded variations* by Brooks/Candeloro (2002, [Zbl 1037.26008 review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1037.26008), pp. 63-81 in [this book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/functional-analysis-vii-proceedings-of-the-postgraduate-school-and-conference-held-at-the-inter-university-centre-dubrovnik-croatia-17-26-september-2001/oclc/51509762)).

Answer (score 0):

As Martin R pointed out, it is possible in some cases, that $f$ is really close to $0$. But in cases like $f(x)\ge m>0$, the integral does not exist.

In particular, if $f(x) = c \neq 0$, it is not integrable, so the case when $g$ is not in $BV(a, b)$ is out of interest to many mathematicians. So like the book Principles of Mathematical Analysis, W. Rudin only deals with monotone integrators.

Comment: How can I prove that if $f(x)=c$ and g  is NOT of bounded variation on  [a,b] then R-S integra doesn't exist?

Comment: By the definition of the integral, you can show that the Riemann sum is unbounded(choose certain partition $\pi_0$) for any refinement of $\pi_0$. Then it would contradict with the existence of integral $I$.